# replacing nested tags of tag with htmlentities by regular expression - PHP

Tags: php, regex

Here is xml code, and I load this text as String and I need all of its nested tags and content to be replaced with htmlentities..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
<target><x id="25e02e3e839c-a1e6b03cb682"  pid="NLSheets" name="NLSheets" />Sheets"</target>
<target>"<x id="3510a371bdf8-861b965564ea" pid="NLTable" name="NLTable" />Table"</target>
<target>"<x id="48a1560eaa68-c400c8394f0a"  pid="NLCaption" name="NLCaption" />Caption"</target>
</data>
```

I have Used the following php code for the task.

```
function html_entities($matches) {
  return str_replace($matches[1], htmlentities($matches[1]), $matches[0]);
}

function get_tag( $tagname, $xml ) {
 $pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>(.*?)<\/$tagname>/"; 
 $content = preg_replace_callback($pattern,  html_entities, $xml);
 return $content;
}

$content = get_tag('target', $str);

echo $content;
```

Now the the problem is with the regular expression. I have used the regular expression

as you can see in get_tag function. `$pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>(.*?)<\/$tagname>/";` which will be built on run time as

```
/<target ?.*>(.*?)<\/target>
```

Now I am unable to fix the problem... The nested tags values are not converted to htmlentities.

Please help

Comment: I agree with SLaks. Use SimpleXML or DOMDocument to manipulate the data.

Comment: hmmm... I need to convert the nested tags to htmlentities, and all of its content + tags are to considered as nodeValue... thats why first i need to convert the xml nodes to htmlentites

Comment: This is pretty much the exact reason that CDATA exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line to this:

```
$pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*?>(.*?)<\/$tagname>/";
```

You need an extra non-greedy modifier to prevent the search for the closing part (`>`) of the opening tag from going too far and grabbing your inner content (and thus not making it available to the parenthetical grouping and thus htmlentities).

We could improve this a little by using the 's' modifier at the end to allow for newlines within the content (since the dot character doesn't include newlines by default) as well as to prevent `/` within the opening tag while allowing newlines there, and allow any kind of whitespace to separate the element name from the attributes and to allow whitespace at the end of the closing tag:

```
$pattern = "/<$tagname(?:\s[^\/]*?)?>(.*?)<\/$tagname\s*>/s";
```

And shorten it:

```
$pattern = "@<$tagname(?:\s[^/]*?)?>(.*?)</$tagname\s*>@s";
```

It is for handling all these possible edge cases that it is safer to use an XML parser. For example, this would not catch:

```
<target><![CDATA[ </target> ]]></target>
```

Comment: can you please fix it? :( I am not good in regular expression.

Comment: I did fix it. There is an extra "?"

Comment: wow great man... only one thing please.. Now when i took the nested tags on next line :( it is doing the job.. i.e. what should I add for covering newline ???

Comment: hats off to you! Thank you so much

Comment: Or another trick is to use `[\s\S]*` if you don't want all dots to allow newlines--this construct will select whitespace or non-whitespace (i.e., any character including newlines).

Comment: Brett's! can you please modify the above regular expression in a way so that it does not catch the unpaired tags e.g. 

`<target />`

Comment: I have modified it again. For the inside content of the opening tag (after the target element name + required white space), I changed `.*?` to `[^/]*?`. This will look for anything which is not a `/` (any number of times), but non-greedy so it won't go past the `>` specified afterward.